# Building a Dirt Jump Bike - Spanish Bottom Bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket, build, jumping

I'm putting together a [Deity Cryptkeeper](https://www.deitycomponents.com/store/p55/DEITY_CRYPTKEEPER_FRAME.html) and confused about which bottom bracket 
to buy...

The specs say: **spanish 73mm Bottom Bracket**

Does this mean 73mm wide and 37mm diameter bearing?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus https://www.deitycomponents.com/cryptkeeper_frame.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd heard of English and French threaded BB shells. My first thought was that it is a mistake, but there is such a thing as 'Spanish' BBs. They are press fit direct into the frame and seem to be specific to BMX and dirt jump MTBs.

https://www.danscomp.com/tech-help/types-of-bottom-brackets/

http://www.moovebikeco.com/mtb/difference-between-euro-mid-and-spanish-bottom-brackets

There seems to be two crank spindle diameters. It would be a good idea to buy cranks and bottom bracket at the same time to make sure they are compatible.

Comment: Sort of only half answers the question though. Could you link to a specific bottom bracket that would fit my frame? I'm worried I might buy the wrong one

Comment: @KolobCanyon Specific product recommendations and buying advice are off topic here (see [What can I ask about here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). I think if you just google "dirt jump spanish bottom bracket" you'll find plenty of options.